# Process hungs with SIGABRT signal handler

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

I am facing problem with signal handler handling SIGABRT signal.While handling SIGABRT, signal handler not able to schedule out. So the other threads are not able to run after someone receives a SIGABRT. This causes improper crash of the program.However, while handling SIGSEGV, it is properly scheduled out and other threads able to run.

Upon receiving signal, I post some recovery mechanism to another thread. For sigsegv it is getting executed, for SIGABRT it is not as the thread is not getting scheduled itself.

FYI : I am using Priority based RR scheduling for my process having > 150 threads.

Comment: You cannot handle the truth. Sorry, I mean SIGABRT. You cannot handle SIGABRT.

Comment: ^^^ - @KerrekSB is funny :)

Answer (score 3):

The ABRT signal cannot be blocked. You can install a handler, but the hander must not return (i.e. it must terminate the process, usually by calling `std::exit` or `_Exit`). If it does return, the signal will be raised again and the default handler will have been installed (which terminates your program).

By contrast, SEGV is an ordinary signal that you can catch, handle and block, but since you cannot fix the *underlying cause* for a typical SEGV, you can't really recover from it sensibly. But you can still exe­cute plenty of code in the meantime.

Comment: @tuban: Remember that signal handlers may only contain async-safe code, which isn't very much.