# Is SIGABRT a blockable signal

Tags: c, linux, signals, abort

Consider the simple example below which registers for a signal handler for SIGABRT, then calls `abort()`. When I run it, the program terminates before printing `Done` but after async-signal-safe printing in the trapped signal.

This implies that SIGABRT is not a blockable signal. This seems to be supported by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12804060/4071435). However, I cannot find any corroborating evidence of that behavior in the [signal man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), which clearly states that `The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored` but makes no similar mention for SIGABRT.

Can someone please enlighten me on this behavior?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

static struct sigaction old_sa;

static void my_handler(int signo)
{
  const char x[] = "In Handler\n";
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, x, strlen(x));
}

int main()
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
  sa.sa_handler = my_handler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGABRT);
  if (0 != sigaction(SIGABRT, &sa, &old_sa))
  {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Ready\n");

  abort();

  printf("Done\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Compiled with `gcc ./try.c && ./a.out` generates the following output

```
Ready
In Handler
Aborted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGABRT` can be blocked. But the `abort()` function unblocks the signal before sending the signal.

This is specified in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/abort.html):

> The `abort()` function shall override blocking or ignoring the `SIGABRT` signal.

You'll get the expected result if you use

```
kill(getpid(), SIGABRT);
```

instead of calling `abort()`

Answer (score 1):

Your handler caught the signal. Then it returned. C 2018 7.22.4.1 2 says “The `abort` function causes abnormal program termination to occur, unless the signal `SIGABRT` is being caught and the signal handler does not return.” So, once your handler returns, the `abort` routine continues doing its thing, which is to terminate your program.

If instead of `abort();` you use `raise(SIGABRT);` to raise the signal without calling the `abort` routine, then the signal handler will be called, will print, and will return, after which `printf("Done\n");` will be executed.